# Android Application Crash

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging

I am working on an android application. It has been working perfectly fine until recently. Whenever I try to install the app via USB to run it on a device, it crashes on the splash screen. Also, when it crashes there are ads at the top of the screen, which I have never added programmatically. When I run the app on an emulator, it works. I thought there was a problem in my manifest but i dont see any problems. Since it doesnt go past the splash screen, here is my code. `

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

Info certificate;
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all info..");
    List<Info> info = db.getAllInfo();

    for (Info cn : info) {

        String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Label: " + cn.getLabel() + " ,Info: " + cn.getInfo();

        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.i("Ids", "" + log);
    }

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = preferences.getString("Certificate","");
    if(name.equals("Validated"))
    {
        splashActions("B");  /* Edit the value here*/
    }
    else
    {
    splashActions("A");
    }

}
public void splashActions(String route)
{

    if(route.equals("A")) {
    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);

                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
    if(route.equals("B"))
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.WallFly">

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>

<uses-sdk
    android:anyDensity="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Actionbarstyle" >

    <!-- Splash Screen Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Intro.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Log In Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Intro.IntroActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <!-- Create Account Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Intro.CreateAccount"
        android:label="@string/create_account"
        android:parentActivityName="com.android.WallFly.Intro.IntroActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.CreateAccountActivity"
            android:value="LoginActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Sign In Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Intro.SignIn"
        android:label="@string/sign_in"
        android:parentActivityName="com.android.WallFly.Intro.IntroActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <!-- Main Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Tabs.MainActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/wfn"
        android:label="@string/empty"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Tabs.ComingSoon"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coming_soon"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Tabs.GrapeVine"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_grape_vine"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Tabs.Notifications"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Tabs.Explore"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_explore"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAy3NwBUS3Bic73TeGvz5vdlwSmrxx4Np0" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Intro.CropperActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cropper"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Profile.Profile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
        //android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.Profile.UserProfile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_profile" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.WallFlyPictureCrop"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wall_fly_picture_crop" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.android.WallFly.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
    </activity>




</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
```

This is what the logcat reads

`02-14 12:07:36.773: W/dalvikvm(2415): PR_CAPBSET_DROP 0 failed: Invalid argument.             Please make sure your kernel is compiled with file capabilities support enabled.`

It prints that out about 30 times then it crashes.

Comment: You never call `super.onCreate(icicle)`

Comment: what is your device version

Comment: @codeMagic its the 3rd call I make in the oncreate.

Comment: @Nava2011 my device is running kikat (4.4.2) and its kernel version is 3.4.0

Comment: Somehow completely missed that, sorry